# How can RxJava interval/infinite counter be implemented with Kotlin Flow in reactive way?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

How can interval counterpart of RxJava interval, infinite counter with delay and time unit, implemented with Flow in reactive way? And how should cancel mechanism work since only way to cancel a Flow is to cancel scope or job of the coroutine and after that coroutine is canceled it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple implementation of RxJava interval.

```
fun interval(timeInMillis: Long, timeUnit: TimeUnit): Flow<Long> = flow {

    var counter: Long = 0

    val delayTime = when (timeUnit) {
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS -> timeInMillis / 1000
        TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS -> timeInMillis / 1_000_000
        TimeUnit.SECONDS -> timeInMillis * 1000
        TimeUnit.MINUTES -> 60 * timeInMillis * 1000
        TimeUnit.HOURS -> 60 * 60 * timeInMillis * 1000
        TimeUnit.DAYS -> 24 * 60 * 60 * timeInMillis * 1000
        else -> timeInMillis
    }

    while (true) {
        delay(delayTime)
        emit(counter++)
    }

}
```

And used it  with launchIn to have `job` similar to `disposable`.

```
val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob())

  val job =  coroutineScope.launch {
        val job = interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .onStart {
                emit(-1)
            }
            .onEach {
                println(it)
            }
            .map {
                "Current time $it"
            }
            .launchIn(coroutineScope)

    }
```

Used another `coroutineScope` to not cancel other `jobs` that are in existing `coroutineScope`, when a `coroutineScope.cancel()` or cancel function of job belong to that coroutineScope is canceled jobs cannot be started again.

Of course this answer might be improved or better one, i don't accept it.